# Getting View=DecorView@f4c156[] not attached to window manager on progressBar.dismiss()

Tags: android, android-studio

```
if(!running)
        {
            running=true;
            boolean connected=checkNet();
            if(connected)
            {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Swalpa taalme.." +
                        "\n" +
                        "ಸ್ವಲ್ಪ ತಾಳ್ಮೆ");

                progressDialog.show(); //ProgressDialog

                final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray a=response.getJSONArray("heroes");
                            for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject obj=a.getJSONObject(i);
                                ListItem m = new ListItem();
                                m.setHead(obj.getString("name"));
                                m.setDesc(obj.getString("about"));
                                m.setImageUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                m.setTrailer(obj.getString("trailer"));
                                listItems.add(m);
                                adapter = new MyNewAdapter(activity,listItems);
                                horizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss(); //Getting error here
                        running=false;

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Sorry, something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        running=false;
                    }
                });
                queue.add(jsObjRequest);
            }
            else running=false;
        }
```

**Please help me out.Getting View not attached on progressbar dismissal.**

> View Decor not attached on progressbar().dismiss.
>   DecorView@f4c156[] not attached to window manager on progressBar.dismiss()
>   View Decor not attached on progressbar().dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
```